# ListBox item in command

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to get the Listboxitem when the user clicks on the button. But in my command the item is always null. Please help to get the item in my command

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
        <Grid ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="5" >                  
            <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=lb, Path=SelectedItem}">
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <ListBox Name="lb" Grid.Row="1"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsList}"  
            Margin="5"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" />
```

ViewModel code

```
    public ICommand MyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_MyCommand == null)
                _MyCommand = new RelayCommand(o => MyCommand_Execute(o));
            return _MyCommand;
        }
    }

    private void MyCommand_Execute(object item)
    {
      //           item is always null
    }
```

Comment: should be like this Command="{Binding DataContext.MyCommand, ElementName=lb}"

Comment: @daniel I don't think that is correct

Comment: @GlenThomas is right. It does not invoke the command

Comment: OK, try {Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}

Comment: And I always like CommandParameter="{Binding}" to provide information for checking. It is very helpful.

Comment: @daniel where do I give the command name ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"

Comment: @daniel Unfortunately it does not work

Comment: That's so strange, can you try CommandParameter="{Binding}" to provide more hints.

Comment: Thanks. CommandParameter="{Binding}" works